# Javascript Audio Library

Tags: javascript, audio, web-applications

I'm a developer/music producer and I would like to combine my passions and make an audio based web app. There is a lot of audio libraries for javascript as I've already researched but I need help selecting one. I need a library that is:
1. Easy to use (well written and easy to set up etc) & 2. Has lots of functionality (Not just playing back audio but manipulating for example and mayb some UI functionality such as a simple audio visualizer)
Thanks

Comment: See [`AudioContext`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext)

Comment: https://musquitojs.com - A simple audio library based on Web Audio Api

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Audio playback feature of HTML5:

```
var audio = new Audio('audiofile.mp3');
audio.play();
```

Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement

There are also several JS libraries which provide basic audio processing:

- Howler: http://goldfirestudios.com/blog/104/howler.js-Modern-Web-Audio-Javascript-Library
- SoundJS: http://www.createjs.com/soundjs
- ProcessingJS: http://processingjs.org/exhibition/